# Addition and Subtraction in Nasm

Tags: nasm

The code just prints out nothing what would I do for the output that will be 150 and 48? I'm practicing nasm

```
section .data
    num1 db 99
    num2 db 51
    result db 0

section .text
    global _start

_start:
    ; Addition
    mov al, [num1]
    add al, [num2]
    mov [result], al
    call display_result

    ; Subtraction
    mov al, [num1]
    sub al, [num2]
    mov [result], al
    call display_result

    ; Exit program
    mov eax, 1
    int 0x80

display_result:
    ; Display result
    mov edx, 1
    mov ecx, [result]
    mov ebx, 1
    mov eax, 4
    int 0x80

    ; Display newline
    mov edx, 1
    mov ecx, 10
    mov ebx, 1
    mov eax, 4
    int 0x80

exit:
    mov eax, 1
    int 0x80`
```

I expect for my coding to print the Addition and Subtraction of Num1 and Num2 but it is not printing what would I do for it to print?

Comment: There's no system call to print integers. You need to convert the result to a string and then print the string.

Comment: what would I add in the code?

Answer (score 0):

See [DIV instruction](https://c9x.me/x86/html/file_module_x86_id_72.html), I think it will best fit your needs. Just divide number by 10 and add the remainder to `ASCII '0'` value and your result will be one digit from the back of the number you are trying to print. For example: `157` will produce `7` remainder first time, `5` second time and then you'll be left with `1` itself. Hope you get the idea.